# React / Redux / Thunk / TypeScript - Dispatch doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I am new to Redux Thunk and reasonably new to TypeScript and I can't get my reducer to fire off when I call Dispatch (`dispatch(updateCountries(countries));`).  I'm using the following packages:

```
"@types/query-string": "^6.1.0",
"@types/react-redux": "^6.0.6",
"@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
"pivotal-ui": "^16.1.0",
"query-string": "^6.1.0",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-scripts-ts": "2.13.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

My state is defined as

```
export interface Country {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export default class AppState {
    countries: Country[];
}
```

I create my store with

```
export type Actions = { type: TypeKeys.UPDATE_COUNTRIES, countries: Country[] } |
    { type: TypeKeys.ADD_ERROR, message: string };

const initialState = localStorage[searchVehicles] ?
JSON.parse(localStorage[searchVehicles]) : new AppState();

const store = createStore(countries, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<AppState, Actions>));
```

I have the following actions

```
export function updateCountries(countries: Country[]): ThunkAction<Country[], AppState, undefined, Actions> {
    return (dispatch, getState) => countries;
}

export function fetchCountries(): ThunkAction<void, AppState, undefined, Actions> {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:49870/api/countries')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(countries => {
            dispatch(updateCountries(countries));
        });
    };
}
```

In my SearchForm, in componentDidMount, I call
`this.props.fetchCoutries();` which is setup through my container, which looks like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    return {
        countries: state.countries
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<AppState, void, Actions>) => {
    return {
        fetchCoutries: () => dispatch(fetchCountries())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchForm);
```

My reducer looks like

```
export const countries = (state: Country[] = [], action: Actions): Country[] => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TypeKeys.UPDATE_COUNTRIES:
            return state;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
};
```

Can anyone see why my reducer isn't getting called?

Comment: I see a lot of code here, but am not really sure what you would like to happen. Can you reduce the code to a simple reproducible problem?

Comment: I've tried to strip it back and added the code for the reducer... Hope this helps :)

Comment: How do you know it’s not getting called?

Comment: The state isn't being populated, so my drop down box is not populated with values... I'm also using VS Code with a break point set that isn't being hit

Comment: offtopic: `typescript-fsa` worth checking

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko is that framework easier? What’s your experience with it?

Comment: it's not a framework, but a small helper for writing redux reducers in typescript in a more typesafe and friendly way

Comment: and I found it to be a very clean and clear approach

Comment: Thanks @DanielKhoroshko, while I couldn't get this code to work, typescript-fsa was much simpler than using a thunk